# Linear Regression for multiple different products in R

Tags: r

[Representation of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej1cQ.png)

I want to make a multiple linear regression for my senior design project. It must be product based. I have lots of different products and their id. there is a sample of the dataset. How can i do this product based? (e.g. from picture: separate regressions for 544555 and 422444)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example. Sharing data from R using `dput()` or similar. How are you setting up your regression for the whole dataset? Perhaps this is a statistics questions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tentative answer given that what exactly you need is not entirely clear.

If we assume a data frame roughly similar to what you have and assume further that `$price` is the outcome variable you wish to explain and that there is some explanatory (independent) variable, called `$indep_var`, we get this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  product = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B"),
  price = c(sample(20, 10)),
  indep_var = c(sample(10))
)
```

Based on this data and these assumptions, you can define a `for` loop to obtain linear regression models for each product:

```
regressions <-c()
for(i in unique(df$product)){
  regressions[i] <- lm(df[df$product==i,]$price ~ df[df$product==i,]$indep_var)
}
regressions
```